# salesforce sites page is acessable without Authentication

Tags: community, force.com-sites

I have VF page, which have been added to Force.com Site to make it accessible to the external user.
Now my problem is that theuser is able to access my VF page without authentication. Salesforce is not asking any authentication.

I have tried by removing my page access following below mentioned steps but external user is not able to access VF page. User is getting insufficient privilege error message.

Go to Setup -> Communities -> All Communities -> click Manage -> Administration -> Pages -> Go to force.com -> Click on public access settings.

Please advise me how to access Salesforce site VF page with authentication?

Answer (score 2):

Please add your pages and controllers in related User profiles.
To prevent access as unauthenticated user, please follow below steps:
Setup -> Develop -> Sites -> Click on Site Name -> Public Access and remove your pages and related classes. Any pages you added under public access, can be accessed by unauthenticated user.

Thanks,
Leanas Nixon.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to implement Authentication for your site.

To enable public login and registration for your portal:
From Setup, enter Sites in the Quick Find box, then select Sites.
1. Click the name of the site you want to control.
2. Click Login Settings.
3. Click Edit.
4. From the Enable Login For list, select a portal to associate with your site. The portal you choose must have the Login Enabled option selected. For Customer Portals, you must also select the Self-Registration Enabled option. Force.com Sites leverages the following portal settings:

[Managing Force.com Site Login and Registration Settings](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sites_login_and_registration_settings.htm&language=en)

[Authenticating Users on Force.com Sites](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Authenticating_Users_on_Force.com_Sites)